# Java: How does a large amount of MouseListeners compare to pixel / grid division?

Tags: java, performance, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

Let's say for example you have a list of items or a large grid of components, and you want to implement some sort of hover/rollover mechanism. The easy way to do this would simply be to add a MouseListener to every component and use the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` methods. Another way that you can do it is to determine the component based on the location of the mouse, for example you have a 2D array of JLabels and you determine which label is under the pointer by using something like:;

```
private void setRolloverIndices(Point p){
   this.rolloverRow = p.y / this.labelHeight;
   this.rolloverCol = p.x / this.labelWidth;
}

private JLabel getRolloverLabel(){
   // assume safe values
   return labels[rolloverRow][rolloverCol];
}
```

Is it worth bothering with pixel / grid calculation, or are listeners generally efficient enough to handle many components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same listener can be added to several components, and the component triggering the event is available using the event's [`getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) or [`getComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentEvent.html#getComponent%28%29) method. No need to guess based on the point location.

Comment: I'm aware that the same listener can be added to many components. But let's say you have that one listener listening for numerous events (such as several mouse / key / focus listeners) on many components... surely if you can use calculation it would be a lot more efficient? I guess my question parallels how efficient listeners are in general.

Comment: a listener is just an object on which a method is called when some event occurs. Its efficiency depends on what it does in this method. One listener or several listeners won't change the time it takes to execute a given method. They're all called sequentially, in a unique thread.